# EJB remote call from standalone client to JBoss server is not working in Multi threading

Tags: spring, multithreading, jboss, jndi, ejb-3.0

I am using spring container in a batch operation that realize many calls to an remote EJB. When the operation is single-thread everything works fine but when try to use multi-threading to gain performance it throws:

```
Exception in thread "taskExecutor-1" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.io.IOException: Channel Channel ID e9c80c0d (outbound) of Remoting connection 18f42160 to servername/ip:port has been closed
```

My stand-alone cliente dependecy is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>7.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm also using spring's SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactory to inject the lookup beans

```
   <bean id="jndiProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="file:/path/jboss-ejb-client.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment" ref="jndiProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="operation" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="ejb:remote/interface/location" />
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="businessInterface" value="com.MyBussinesInterfae" />
    </bean>
```

In my tests I verified that if a Thread-A creates the InitContext and does the JNDI EJB lookup and creates the instance of the EJB remote inferface (under the `SRSSPFBean`) it can invoke methods via the EJB remote interface, but if an Thread-B gets the reference of the EJB remote interface and tries to invoke a method the exception is thrown.

The only similiar problem found on my search is [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/204139?start=0&tstart=0#thread-message-754517) and seems related to bugs on Jboss AS 7. I am using Jboss eap 6.2.

Thanks in advance for any help.